# Rake precompile breaks Javascript with undefined error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, angularjs, asset-pipeline, ng-grid

I'm using ng-grid with Rails and have replicated the first example on the home page, where:

```
<div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="availOptions"></div>
$scope.arr = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                 {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                 {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                 {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                 {name: "Enos", age: 34}]

$scope.availOptions = {
data: 'arr'
}
```

This works great before assets have been precompiled. But after running

```
$ rake assets:precompile
```

we suddenly get two tables -- see http://grab.by/t2dm -- and the error:

Cannot call method 'selectionHandlers' of undefined

I have searched for this problem extensively and could not find any other help online. So I thought I would post here as I have been trying to debug this for the past few days. Help!

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar w/the issues around minifying Javascript and AngularJS? If your code is breaking after precompiling the assets, that is likely your problem. Try a google search on "angularjs minification" or read the section on minification on [this page](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running in development? If so, you almost certainly need to turn off asset debugging. Otherwise, all your scripts and stylesheets will be duplicated, as you're getting both the concatenated/minified version, and the uncompiled version.

The issue is with `javascript_include_tag "application.js"`.

Basically, in development, it gets expanded to a bunch of lines like this:

```
<script src="application.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="my-file1.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="my-file2.js?body=1"></script>
... etc ...
```

In production, with asset debugging turned off, you see the single concatenated file, with its asset pipeline fingerprint:

```
<script src="application.js-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.js"></script>
```

The issue is, in development, once you've compiled your assets that first `application.js?body=1` contains **all** of your scripts. But then the scripts are included a second time by the subsequent lines.

Look at the source for your site; if you have a single `<script src="application-xxxxxxxx.js"></script>`, then asset debugging is off, and this answer won't be useful. If you have one `<script>` per source file, asset debugging is on, and you'll have two copies of each script running.

This happens very often when you precompile your assets, but continue running your app in your development environment, where asset debugging is on by default. The development environment and precompiled assets are *not* compatible; once you've precompiled assets, you need to kill your server and restart it with `RAILS_ENV=production`, assuming your development copy has been setup with a sane pseudo-production configuration.

Comment: Thank you x1000!  You are exactly right.  I was testing the rake assets:precompile before deployment and thought it was an issue with ng-grid. Thank you!!